# Disk replace breaks disk naming convention in zpool

Tags: solaris, zfs, nexenta, zpool

After replacing two broken disks in my RAID-Z2 pool, the output of `zpool status` looks strange. The disks are addressed with their full path and also seem to contain 'slices', which all other disk don't.

I entered these commands to replace the broken disks (which might explain the strange naming, but not the slices):

```
zpool replace bashpool c2t6d0 /dev/rdsk/c2t6d0
zpool replace bashpool c2t7d0 /dev/rdsk/c2t7d0
```

The output of zpool status now reports as:

```
~$ zpool status -v bashpool 
pool: bashpool
state: ONLINE
scan: resilvered 1.01T in 39h31m with 0 errors on Fri Feb 22 10:50:20 2013
config:

    NAME                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bashpool                ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t0d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t1d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t2d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t3d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t4d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t5d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        /dev/rdsk/c2t6d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        /dev/rdsk/c2t7d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t4d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t5d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t6d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t7d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t1d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t3d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t2d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      c3t0d0                AVAIL
errors: No known data errors
```

My questions are:

- Did I do anything wrong? The pool seems to be fine, but as I am not that experienced with Solaris I can't really say. If so, how can I remedy the situation?
- Can disk names in a zpool be altered?
- Why do the new disks seem to have slices, when all the other disks don't? I did not format them, just installed the new, raw disks into the server and ran the replace command.

Update 2013-02-25: Now I do not seem to be able to control the two devices any more; any `zpool` command seems to fail with the error 'no such device in pool':

```
~# zpool detach bashpool /dev/dsk/c2t6d0s0
   cannot detach /dev/dsk/c2t6d0s0: no such device in pool

~# zpool detach bashpool c2t6d0s0
   cannot detach /dev/dsk/c2t6d0s0: no such device in pool
```

Even stranger: I can address the devices by GUID (found out via `zdb -C <zpool>`), but only `zpool offline` seems to work:

```
~# zpool offline bashpool '683230688581832563'
~# zpool status
  pool: bashpool
  state: DEGRADED
  status: One or more devices has been taken offline by the administrator.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
  action: Online the device using 'zpool online' or replace the device with
    'zpool replace'.
  scan: resilvered 1.01T in 39h31m with 0 errors on Fri Feb 22 10:50:20 2013
  config:

    NAME                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bashpool                DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0              DEGRADED     0     0     0
        c2t0d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t1d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t2d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t3d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t4d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c2t5d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        /dev/rdsk/c2t6d0s0  OFFLINE      0     0     0
        /dev/rdsk/c2t7d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t4d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t5d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t6d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t7d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t1d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t3d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
        c3t2d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      c3t0d0                AVAIL   

errors: No known data errors
```

I can online the device afterwards but I do not seem to be able to do anything else with the devices. Every other command returns the error 'no such device in pool'.  Does anyone know of another way to control zpool devices?

Comment: Can you give the output of `zpool status -V`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm a little embarrased to admit, but the zpool command on this system doesn't seem to have the '-V' parameter (that is a capital V, isn't it?). A small '-v' yields the same output as an normal 'zpool status' command without any arguments. The system is a now end-of-life Nexenta Core 3, which is a Ubuntu 8.04 LTS / Solaris 10 hybrid (don't ask...). As for the size: the pool consists of 16x2tb disks in raid-z2 configuration with one disk as a hotspare.

Comment: Sorry, I meant lower-case "v".

Comment: update question as per request, although the output is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

The slice visibility occurs during the resilvering operation. When it's complete, the normal device names are usually restored.

As for your `zpool replace` operation, you only needed to use the device name. Not the full path.

(by the way, that's a crazy-large raidz2 pool!!)